# psycopg2 installing error in cPanel while hosting Django Website with PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, cpanel

Collecting psycopg2
Using cached psycopg2-2.9.3.tar.gz (380 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [23 lines of output]
running egg_info
creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-irgb8yga/psycopg2.egg-info
writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-irgb8yga/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-irgb8yga/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-irgb8yga/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-irgb8yga/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

```
  Error: pg_config executable not found.

  pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
  containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
  option:

      python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

  or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

  If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
  'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

  For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
  <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).

  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Answer (score 1):

As recommended in the log try using `psycopg2-binary` as package not `psycopg2`.
That's how I use it and it's working on all different environments.